# Complex Atlas for Elliptic Curves over $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis, elliptic-curves, riemann-surfaces

I know that every elliptic curve over $\mathbb{C}$ is isomophic to a torus $\mathbb{C}/\Lambda$ in the sense of Riemann Surfaces, moreover $E(\Lambda)$  as topological subspace of $\mathbb{P}^2(\mathbb{C})$ is connected, has a countable basis and is Hausdorff, but what is the complex atlas for $E(\Lambda)$ ?

Comment: $\Lambda$ divides $\mathbb{C}$ into parallelograms that are identified by the quotient map $\pi$. If you choose carefully an open set $U\subset \mathbb{C}$, the restriction of $\pi$ to $U$ will be injective. Since $E$ has the quotient topology $(\pi|_{U})^{-1}$ will be a chart.

Comment: What is your'e $E(\Lambda)$ means ?